# Calculate the storage size of mysql records

Tags: mysql, storage

I am working on an employee management project in which a feature is to resell specific modules to other companies so that they could also use this system. And all the administration will be handed over to super admin. And the storage spaces will also be allotted to companies. Now, How can i calculate the storage space for a specific company. Because there are different tables in which the all companies data is stored. So, how can i caluclate the storage space for a specific company or seller through the MySQL rows or records from different tables?

```
Example:

company Table:
ID, Name

Department Table:
ID, Name company_id

Employee Table:
ID Name, department_ID
```

Comment: This is an absolutely horrible idea. Don't use the same database for storing the data of multiple customers. Make a new database for each customer. (This way you see how much space each customer uses, and you can apply per-customer access controls.)

Comment: *Calculate the storage size of mysql records* You may, of course. But after determining the data size for each user you'll find that total occupied disk size is greater that total sum of particular data size. And the difference can be extreme - up to 10 times and even more. So your need makes no sense.